# How to wrap and center headers, AND right-justify column data in pgfplotstable

Tags: pgfplotstable

I'm using pgfplotstable to import csv data into a table.  The headers need to be long words that take too much width and need to be wrapped, the row contents are only about 14 chars (decimals).  So far I have been able to EITHER wrap and center, without right-justifying the data, OR right-justify with no wrapping.  I need both.

```
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma, every head row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule\endhead}, 
every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
columns={pn,DetConv,DetTak,HypConv,HypTak}, 
columns/pn/.style={column name=$p_n$,fixed,precision=1},
    columns/DetConv/.style={column type=r, column name=Deterministic - Convolution,fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=12},
    columns/DetTak/.style={column type=r, column name=Deterministic - Takacs,fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=12},
    columns/HypConv/.style={column type=r, column name=Hyperexponential - Convolution,fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=12},   
columns/HypTak/.style={column type=r, column name=Hyperexponential - Takacs,fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=12}
    ]{table.csv}
```

I found a "black box" suggestion to use
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{8em}}
which gives me correct headers but no right-justification of the data.  No explanation of what those parameters are actually doing or where to find more info (style options not provided in the pgfplotstable manual).
Would be nice to get this right, but it has wasted a lot of time so far - helpful suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! Your chances of getting a good and timely answer will increase dramatically if you provide us with a complete document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`, contains a just large enough data file and illustrates what you have tried.

Comment: Probably replacing centering with flushrigh works.